# Is there a way to get the latest data of 10,000 tables in TDengine?

Tags: database, tdengine

I have a supertable called `sdata` in TDengine database, 10,000 subtables to store the data from 10,000 IoT sensors. I named the tables data_1,data_2 ...

I want to take the latest data of each point when I initialize the service. Of course, I can query all these tables.

I don't know is there a way to get the results by one sql statement?

Answer (score 0):

According the [documention](https://docs.tdengine.com/taos-sql/function/#), may be you can try last_row function.

SQL statement:

```
select tbname,last_row(*) from sdata group by tbname;
```